# What role does the hydrosphere play in tectonic plate convection?

Tags: plate-tectonics, ozone, lithosphere

I need to do a "how do different 'Earth's spheres' interact with each other" and I'm trying to figure out how the hydrosphere would affect the lithosphere if the ozone layer were to disappear. 'Ozone Depletion.'

This is a project for my High school environmental science course.

Comment: Hi Ryla, welcome... a good starting point here is to show us you know what the terms mean.  StackExchange isn't a place where people just generally put together fantastic answers for your needs, you kind of have to be a part of it... tell us about those two spheres and how you can picture them already interacting, and then what the ozone layer does, and you may be working closer to getting to what you're needing.

Comment: It's also true that so far you have a rather broad and open-ended question, so it's harder to focus down to answers... the Earth Science [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=earthscience.stackexchange.com) may be a way to get more back and forth input until you've narrowed down your thinking/question (it's an open public chat, and really asynchronous, so it's more like the input you used to be able to get on message boards if there are reasonable active people, rather than what many may think of as a chat these days)

Answer (score 1):

Lubrication.
Not to mention hydrothermal vents which feat ecosystems that at the depth do not depend on sunlight

Comment: I agree the main effect of water in plates movement is [lubrication of the boundaries in the subduction zones](https://scholar.google.es/scholar?hl=es&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=water+tectonic+plates+lubrication&btnG=#d=gs_qabs&u=%23p%3DFXQlARkzEpUJ). Perhapps you could elaborate a bit more your answer.